# access denied ("java.net.SockerPermission" "irc.esper.net" "resolve")

Tags: java, resolve

I'm getting this error in my applet when I run the applet embedded in a webpage:
acess denied ("java.net.SockerPermission" "irc.esper.net" "resolve")

It works fine when I run the applet otherwise...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just like this. You dont talk to strangers! the same way, an unsigned applet is a stranger if it is accessing from outside. Signing is just a process of establishing a trust between two entities. that is your system shall agree to provide permissions for this applet on a run.

You need to sign the applets using a digital certificate. i think you have a basic idea on certificates. you can generate certificates using `keytool` in java. After you generate, there should be a common trustee (Certified Authority[CA]) to say your certificate is valid and not a fake one. the imprint of that CA is called signed certificate.

You can also have a self-signed certificate. But the browsers will show a warning that certificate is not trusted, and ask the user that whether to trust?!. If user says Ok, then ur certificate is added to browsers Truststore.

Please go through some documentations on this. http://www.herongyang.com  shall be a good option for some hand-on!

Answer (score 3):

If your applet is unsigned, it is only allowed to open sockets to the same host from which it is loaded by the web browser. So, you need to either host your applet on irc.esper.net or obtain a signature for it. A self-signed certificate is sufficient for this (obviously, the user will have to confirm the notice that appears).

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/rsa_signing.html for instructions on signing.

Comment: Then you should look into Java's security model for a bit. Here's some more background information for your specific case: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html